How is TPS applied on two halves of payload fairing separation line when they joined together?
This is a basic question, but I really want to know how a TPS can be applied on two halves of the fairing joint line. We see in pictures that many fairing halves have cork tiles and their joint (separation) line cover with a cord or belt type material.

I read that SpaceX uses pentagon shaped TPS tiles to avoid heat penetration during ascent. So how do other fairings protect their separation line during ascent?

I think payload fairings are jettisoned relatively early in the flight and do not reach anywhere near orbital speed so TPS is not the sort of problem we see with objects entering Earth's atmosphere at orbital velocity. Also may fairings are not reused.

Payload fairings are used on ascent from launchpad to orbit but not for a reentry from orbit to ground. The fairings are separated when the air pressure outside is very, very low and the payload does not need a protection during the final flight to orbit.  The thermal stress of a fairing is much lower than that of a heat shield used for reentry from orbit to ground.

do you have an example of the cork-tile-covered fairings you refer to?

https://www.compositesworld.com/articles/plant-tour-ruag-space-decatur-alabama-us

http://www.satnews.com/story.php?number=350965362

We also see M/S AMORIM and Narcot Liege cork ablative products in the market with long history to use them in Space.

https://ec.europa.eu/research/participants/documents/downloadPublic?documentIds=080166e5b86a9ef4&appId=PPGMS

AAA! (Acronymology Assistance Alert)- what is TPS?

Thermal Protection System

Um.... Yeah.... so we're putting cover sheets on all TPS questions now, so if you could just remember to do that, that'd be greaaaaaat.
